# exchangeability in LDA

Tags: machine-learning, probability, inference, latent-dirichlet-alloc, exchangeability

Can someone help me understand how exchangeability works for Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) and how it enables us to treat words in the test set that are not present in the training set?
I know that LDA is by nature an exchangeable model, and I know the basic definition of exchangeability and how probability does not change subject to permutation. The thing that I am not sure about is the real-life implications of that on a model like LDA and how this really works in detail.

I would appreciate any thorough explanation or good references.